# Strange problem with VSS: VSS doesn't work after 5 p.m

Tags: visual-studio, visual-sourcesafe

I have a very strange problem with Visual Source Safe. I use VSS as a add-on with VS 2008 in a corporate intranet with 5 other colleagues. My VS stops working after 5 p.m. most of days with complaining can not connect Source Safe. I'm running VS 2008 and VSS 2005 on Vista and no other one in corporate have such a problem.

What do you think about its cause? 
Is there any log for VSS?

Comment: At that time can you use Explorer to get to the VSS Share folder directly?

Comment: Maybe someone switches the server off when they leave to go home.

Comment: Is this a joke? :D You're just looking for an excuse not to work after 5?

Comment: mdm: That's what I thought at first, but he mentioned that no one else is having the same problem (I assume that means that they are there after 5pm on the same days he is.)

Comment: How do you connect to VSS, using the client, from within VS or over the web? The client connects via file sharing so maybe something on the server is disabling your user's file rights for some reason

Comment: This sounds like one of the ads for Vault. "Hi, I'm a SourceSafe user. I'm better than this. I can work after 5 p.m. I can."

Comment: @Ruddy: I never tried this but will test it in next occurrence.

Comment: @mdm: No, sever is working. Because other colleagues are using VSS with no problem at the same time I had difficulties with it. Indeed when I restart my own machine everything goes OK.

Comment: @Younes: No! I love my work even after 5 p.m.

Comment: @Anders: I'm connecting within VS via a shared folder not a web connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably have logon restrictions on your domain account.

VSS is a file based source control system and it works via access to a net work share.  Account logon restrictions would prevent you from gaining access to the share at certain times.

To test this theory try this:

1. Get the share that VSS lives in.  It should be in the form `\\SERVER\SHARE`.
2. Open a command prompt
3. Type **NET USE** this will show you all your connections
4. If connected to the share type **NET USE Z: /delete** (with Z: being the assigned drive letter for that share)
5. Type **`NET USE * \\SERVER\SHARE`**

If this theory is correct, before 5 your will get *command completed sucessfully*, but after 5 you will get *access denied*

Comment: @Mark: I will try you guidelines next time the problem occurs and write back result here.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of questions

1. Has it ever worked past 5pm?  If it has is there an event you can correlate to when it stopped working?
2. Can you access VSS through VSS Explorer when you can't access it through VS.NET
3. Is the VSS database on a remote server or shared drive?  If so can you access that drive after 5pm?  VSS is just a bunch of files on the disk.  Can you see those files outside of VSS or VS.NET?
4. Any chance someone is doing a backup or something similar to the VSS machine that is bringing the box down?  Can you ping the VSS server after 5pm?

Comment: 1.a. Yes, my colleagues are using it event when I have trouble with this. Additionally many times it worked for myself after 5 p.m.
--
1.b. This problem occurs more in busy days that the network users are doubled.
--
2. No. If I can't access via VS then I can not access through VSS Explorer too.
--
3.a. It's on a shared folder on a server in out corporate internal network. Additional there is no Firewall or Router or any network equipments between our machines and the server.
--
3.b. I didn't try this one. But I will test it in next occurrence of the problem.
--
4.a. No. 
--
4.b. Must test it.